# Light box size is not correct while opening up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am not sure how to adjust the window size of the light box.
When I click the cube the light box opens up;
I have given links in the light box but the problem is when light box opens up the size of the light box width size is not correct while opening up.

http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8YK2n/

```
 onClick: function() {
    if (!Gallery._config.lightbox) return !1;
    Gallery._toggleOverlay(!0);
    Gallery._current = $(this).parent();
    var a = $(this),
        a = a.children('div[class="' + a.data("position") + '"]').children("img"),
        b = a.data("width"),
        c = a.data("height"),
        f = a.data("container_width"),
        h = a.data("container_height"),
        g = a.data("caption"),
        d = Gallery.window_width - 100,
        j = g ? Gallery.window_height - 180 : Gallery.window_height - 120;
    if (b > d || c > j) {
        var k = b / c;
        k < d / j ? (c = j, b = k * c) : (b = d, c = b / k)
    }
    var m = $("<div>").addClass("caption").html(g ? g : ""),
        n = $("<img>").attr("src", a.attr("src")).width(f).height(h),
        d = $("<div>").addClass("prev").attr("title", "Previous").click(Gallery._prev),
        j = $("<div>").addClass("next").attr("title", "Next").click(Gallery._next);
    Gallery._lightbox = $("<div>").attr("id", "melonhtml5_lightbox").append(n).append(m).append(d).append(j).appendTo($(document.body)).data("container", {
        left: a.offset().left,
        top: a.offset().top,
        width: f,
        height: h,
        caption: g
    });
    var l = $(window).scrollTop(),
        e = $(window).scrollLeft(),
        d = function() {
            n.animate({
                width: b,
                height: c
            }, Gallery.lightbox_speed);
            Gallery._lightbox.animate({
                left: Gallery.window_width / 2 - b / 2 + e,
                top: Gallery.window_height / 2 - c / 2 + l
            }, Gallery.lightbox_speed, function() {
                g && m.animate({
                    height: 30
                }, Gallery.lightbox_speed)
            })
        };
    switch (Gallery._config.animation) {
        case "default":
            Gallery._lightbox.css({
                left: a.offset().left,
                top: a.offset().top
            });
            Gallery._lightbox.animate({
                left: Gallery.window_width / 2 - f / 2 + e,
                top: Gallery.window_height / 2 - h / 2 + l
            }, Gallery.lightbox_speed, d);
            break;
        case "drop":
            Gallery._lightbox.css({
                left: Gallery.window_width / 2 - f / 2 + e,
                top: -1 * h + l
            });
            Gallery._lightbox.animate({
                top: Gallery.window_height / 2 - h / 2 + l
            }, Gallery.lightbox_speed, d);
            break;
        case "slide":
            Gallery._lightbox.css({
                left: -1 * f + e,
                top: Gallery.window_height / 2 - h / 2 + l
            }), Gallery._lightbox.animate({
                left: Gallery.window_width / 2 - f / 2 + e
            }, Gallery.lightbox_speed, d)
    }
    Gallery._config.slideshow && !Gallery._in_slideshow && (Gallery._in_slideshow = !0, setTimeout(Gallery._slideshow, Gallery._config.slideshow_speed))
},
```

Answer (score 0):

When you added your links you set wrong style, it coursed to wide window in case image small.

```
<div class="caption" style="height: 30px; text-align: right;">
   <a style="font-size: 18px;" href="/Sales/order/">Create</a> 
   <div> 
     <a href="/Sales/" style="font-size: 18px;">View/Edit</a> 
   </div> 
   <a style="&nbsp;font-size: 18px;">Labels</a>
</div>
```

You need change all tags like

```
 <div class="cubeCell" data-text="Search" data-caption="&lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' href='http://www.w3schools.com/' &gt;Create&lt;/a&gt; &lt;div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;View/Edit&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;a style='margin-left: 92px; font-size: 18px; color: grey;' &gt;Labels&lt;/a&gt;" data-image="http://intra.defie.co/images/Desktop_icons_02.07.13/search.png"><div class="cubeTextStyle">Search</div></div>
```

Comment: i did not get you....can you update in the fiddle for one cube http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/8YK2n/